# Move vehicle towards the cursor

Tags: java, movement, mouse

I am making a game similar to Asteroids. The ship always points toward the mouse cursor. I want to know how to move towards the mouse so if I press `w` I will drive towards the mouse and if I press `s` I will move away from the mouse. How can I do this? Here is my code so far:

```
public class player {

    public int x,y;
    private Image img;

    float xDistance;
    float yDistance;
    double rotationAngle;

    public player(int x,int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void tick(){
         xDistance = Comp.mx - x;
         yDistance = Comp.my - y;
         rotationAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(yDistance, xDistance));
         handleinput();
    }

    public void render(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_GASP);
        g2.setRenderingHints(rh);

        ImageIcon i2 = new ImageIcon("res/player.png");
        img = i2.getImage();

        AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y);
        at.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotationAngle) ,20,20);

        g2.drawImage(img, at, null);



    }

    public void handleinput(){
        if(Keys.isPressed(Keys.w)){

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few steps that you need to follow to accomplish this goal, they are as follows:

- Get the distance that the player has moved (i.e. the amount of time the w key has been pressed times some sort of speed multiplier)
- Calculate the distance along the x- & y-axis that the ship should be displaced using the trigonometric functions sine and cosine
- Move the ship relative to these amounts

---

The diagram below shows how the vertical and horizontal displacements relate to the distance the player moved in the asteroids game.

[image: player movement mechanics]

Suppose that your cursor makes an angle that is 30 degrees, or π/6 radians, relative to the x-axis and the ship moves a total of 15 pixels toward its target. The horizontal displacement of the ship is then **`15×cos(π/6)=12.99≈13 pixels`** and the vertical displacement is **`15×sin(π/6)=7.5≈8 pixels`**.

Hope that helps, and sorry for the lack of code. I'm not that familiar with the native Java libraries for drawing graphics.